# How to get values from list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

This is my data set, this is the column I separated from the csv file.

```
0    [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, '...
1    [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, '...
2    [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, ...
3    [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'nam...
4                       [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
```

How to get just a list with the content `['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Romance', 'Comedy', 'Comedy']` as output?

Comment: Add a sample of the expected output you are considering

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to see something like that.

```
    list_of_items = [[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation2'}],[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation3'}, {'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation4'}]]

    output_list = []
    for item in list_of_items:
        for dict in item:
            output_list.append(dict['name'])
```

Output:

```
>>> print(output_list)
['Animation', 'Animation2', 'Animation3', 'Animation4']
```

Comment: Hey, I have tried that method, I believe that the list of dictionaries is a string in a list. So I'm not able to use them as dictionaries and lists

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you made a typo but you have some errors with the ' in what you wrote.

But nevertheless from what I can see you have a list with dictionaries. So we loop through that list to access each dictionary and select what in the dictionary we want and append it to the list you created:

```
d = [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
list_1 = []

for el in d:

    list_1.append(el['name'])

print(list_1)
```

The output will be: `['Romance', 'Comedy']`

Comment: The data I have given is a column "genres" from the csv file. I tried the method you gave, but I got the error , "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: Can you send me the file so I can see if I understand why you got the error?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you have a list of lists or just one list.

For a single list you can use a list comprehension:

```
dict_list = [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[dict_item['name'] for dict_item in dict_list]
```

Otherwise, you can unnest the first list and then do a list comprehension

```
dict_list = [[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Comedy'}],[{'id': 3, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'Comedy'}]]
[dict_item['name'] for dict_item in [dict_item for sublist in dict_list for dict_item in sublist]]
```